# Apache2 Authentication to access a website is not accepted

Tags: apache, authentication

I use Apache2 to intervene between my site and the User with an Authentication Login dialogue. I've added a hashed password to the Apache2 .htaccess file. The Site has a registered subdomain, and the web server has a set of SSL certs and keys. However, when a User tries to access the site and they are presented with the Username & Password box, the username and password are not accepted. I would appreciate some help.

I create a Username and Password for the site authentication using:

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
```

I can see a hashed version of the password in that file.

Then, these are my Apache2 server configuration files:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/my-site.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName my-site.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.my-site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-site/public_html


    <Directory /var/www/my-site/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Location "/">
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "Restricted Area"
        AuthDigestDomain /
        AuthDigestProvider file
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.my-site.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.my-site.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And the main apache config file **/etc/apache2/apache.conf**

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess
#<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
#        Require all denied
#</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

My **/etc/apache/httpd.conf** file is empty, and I do not have a **.htaccess** file.

I've cleared the cache, used private browsers, and I've asked others to try, but ultimately the password and username I set don't work.

Please tell me if I'm missing data for you to help. I'm happy to edit the question. Thanks

**Edit**

I noticed the following:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

I commented it out, restarted the server, and tried again in a fresh private browser. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have inconsistent file names for the password file (the htpasswd commands misses a `/` ).

htpasswd command:

> ```
> sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2.htpasswd
> ```

my-site.conf:

> ```
> AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
> ```

The first command creates a file `/etc/apache2.htpasswd` the config expects the file `/etc/apache2/.htpasswd` (extra `/`)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I think it could have been a typo when I added the command to my post. I tried again (just incase), and nothing had changed. I have also corrected the typo in my post. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Because I'm using digest authentication I should be generating usernames and passwords using e.g.

```
sudo htdigest -c digestpassword the_realm the_username
```

I then had to adjust my <Location "/"> directive in my .conf file, to consider this change e.g.,

```
<Location "/">
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "the_realm"
        AuthDigestDomain /var/www/my_site/public_html
        AuthDigestProvider file
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/digestpassword
        Require valid-user
</Location>
```